# Error when trying to generate genesis block for raft

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, raft

**EDIT: It was because, I had put orderer type etcdraft in normal orderer config in configtx.yaml which was causing it to find the remaining config i the same object instead of from overridden object in profile**.

This is the error I am getting when trying to generate the raft orderer genesis.block

This error doesn't say anything specific as to what it is missing. I compared the yaml file with the first network's sample yaml file and both are same.

```
2019-06-20 13:46:04.944 IST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 002 orderer type: etcdraft
2019-06-20 13:46:04.944 IST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 003 Orderer.EtcdRaft.Options unset, setting to tick_interval:"500ms" election_tick:10 heartbeat_tick:1 max_inflight_blocks:5 snapshot_interval_size:20971520 
2019-06-20 13:46:04.944 IST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] Load -> INFO 004 Loaded configuration: /Users/shubham.kumar/Desktop/repos/blockahead_baas/configtx.yaml
2019-06-20 13:46:04.974 IST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 005 orderer type: etcdraft
2019-06-20 13:46:04.975 IST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> PANI 006 etcdraft raft configuration missing
2019-06-20 13:46:04.975 IST [common.tools.configtxgen] func1 -> PANI 007 etcdraft raft configuration missing
panic: etcdraft raft configuration missing [recovered]
    panic: etcdraft raft configuration missing

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore.(*CheckedEntry).Write(0xc000447080, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore/entry.go:229 +0x515
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).log(0xc00000c248, 0xc0001a5604, 0xc00034b980, 0x23, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:234 +0xf6
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).Panicf(0xc00000c248, 0xc00034b980, 0x23, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:159 +0x79
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging.(*FabricLogger).Panic(0xc00000c250, 0xc0001a5768, 0x1, 0x1)
    /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging/zap.go:73 +0x75
main.main.func1()
    /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/main.go:260 +0x1a9
panic(0x163d3a0, 0xc00033f000)
    /opt/go/go1.11.5.linux.amd64/src/runtime/panic.go:513 +0x1b9
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore.(*CheckedEntry).Write(0xc000447080, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore/entry.go:229 +0x515
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).log(0xc00000c228, 0x4, 0x17659b1, 0x1d, 0xc0001a5c10, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:234 +0xf6
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).Panicf(0xc00000c228, 0x17659b1, 0x1d, 0xc0001a5c10, 0x1, 0x1)
    /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:159 +0x79
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging.(*FabricLogger).Panicf(0xc00000c230, 0x17659b1, 0x1d, 0xc0001a5c10, 0x1, 0x1)
    /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging/zap.go:74 +0x60
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/localconfig.(*Orderer).completeInitialization(0xc0001863f0, 0xc0002574c0, 0x32)
    /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/localconfig/config.go:397 +0xcf3
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/localconfig.(*TopLevel).completeInitialization(0xc00050f9f0, 0xc0002574c0, 0x32)
    /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/localconfig/config.go:303 +0xaf
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/localconfig.LoadTopLevel(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/localconfig/config.go:243 +0x4ca
main.main()
    /w/workspace/fabric-release-jobs-x86_64/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/configtxgen/main.go:278 +0xcab
make: *** [generate_arts_raft] Error 2
Chosen raft for consensus
```

What am I doing wrong?

My configtx.yaml file link: https://pastebin.com/32q6UAcZ

Answer (score 0):

In your `configtx.yaml`, line `217`, you have:

```
OrdererType: etcdraft
```

However you didn't provide the complete `etcdraft` configuration, like:

```
OrdererType: etcdraft
EtcdRaft:
  Consenters:
  - Host:
    Port:
    ClientTLSCert:
    ServerTLSCert:
```

Comment: Yeah I figured that out. I have put the same thing on the top of the question.